# Handle RequestTooLargeError exception in Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When i try to insert 1000+ list into appengine datastore, i gout this error `RequestTooLargeError: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.`

Tried to import this

```
from google.appengine.ext.db import RequestTooLargeError
try:
    .....
except RequestTooLargeError:
    logging.error("RequestTooLargeError")
```

But getting `ImportError: cannot import name RequestTooLargeError`

How to catch this `RequestTooLargeError` exception in appengine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception is on this module:

```
from google.appengine.runtime.apiproxy_errors import RequestTooLargeError
```